# Deleting a string between two carriage returns tsql

Tags: string, t-sql, replace

Very new to SQL so I appreciate your patience in advance.
I have a column in a table that stores a particular set of instructions; each instruction is encapsulated by a carriage return.
eg: `char(13)+ @instruction1 + char(13)`...
`@Instruction1` is a string  of variable length but I do know a certain part of the string eg: `@instruction1 = some string + @knownstring + some string.`
So we have `char(13) + (some string + @knownstring + some string) +char(13)`.
I want to replace this entire line with ''.
Identifying it just using the `@knownstring`.

Is this possible?

Thanking you all again, I really appreciate your assistance

```
select replace(replace(column,@knownsting,''),char(13),'') 
from table 
where key=1235
```

Replaces only the `@knownstring` but I also need to replace the surrounding text between the two `char(13)`

Comment: Could you please add an example and an expected result? I don't get what exactly should be done.

Comment: The SSMS version is irrelevant. We need to know the SQL Serer version. If you don't know what it is, please run `SELECT @@Version` and find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something along this:

```
DECLARE @KnownString VARCHAR(50)='Keep This'
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(MAX)='blah' + CHAR(13) + 'dummy keep this dummy more' + CHAR(13) + 'Something without the known part' + CHAR(13) + 'Again with Keep THIS';

SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT CHAR(13) + CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@KnownString,LineText)>0 THEN @KnownString ELSE LineText END
    FROM (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@YourString,CHAR(13),'</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted)
    CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes('/x') B(fragment)
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT fragment.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')) C(LineText)
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```

The result

```
blah
Keep This
Something without the known part
Keep This
```

### The idea

The string is transformed to XML by replacing the line breaks with XML tags. Now we can query all text lines separately, check them for the known string, do the needed manipulation, and finally reconcatenate all fragments using the XML-trick (together with `STUFF` to get rid of the leading `CHAR(13)`).

### Remarks

Using v2016 I'd use the split-string approach with `OPENJSON` and starting with v2017 there is `STRING_AGG()` to make the reconcatenation easier.

Comment: Thanks so much mate, really appreciate your elegant solution!